# How to specify the buffer size for websockets?

Tags: websocket, ballerina

I am using ballerina in order to make a proxy. I am trying to receive a message that exceeds the default websocket buffer limit of 65536.

I tried to find the parameter of the websocket configuration that allows me to set this size, but I can't find it in the official documentation. Right now the websocket is configured as follows:

```
ttp:WebSocketClient wsClientEp = new(
            EXTRACTOR,
            {callbackService: ClientService,
            readyOnConnect: false
            });
```

I get the following error on response:

```
2019-10-14 09:45:18,230 ERROR [] - Unexpected error hense closing the connection : error {ballerina/http}WsGenericError message=Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
```

Comment: Please refer: https://riyafa.wordpress.com/2019/01/06/demystifying-websocket-in-ballerina-websocketlistener-websocketcaller-websocketclient/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `maxFrameSize` for this. Here's the [documentation link](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http/records/WebSocketClientConfiguration.html)

```
http:WebSocketClient wsClient = new(
    EXTRACTOR,
    {
        callbackService: ClientService,
        readyOnConnect: false,
        maxFrameSize: <YOUR BUFFER SIZE>
    }
)
```